# Ignorar multiples condiciones en PHP

Tags: php

Tengo la siguiente duda tengo un if q si es un proceso muestra unas cosas pero si es cualquier otro muestra otras cosas. 
A simple vista así:

```
<?php

if($proceso == 'Tp'){
    echo "Todo esto que ve TP";
}
else{
   echo "Todas estas cosas que ven los otro";
}

?>
```

Como puedo agregar un proceso que vea lo que ve 'Tp' y lo que ven los otros, que Tp vea lo de Tp, los otros vean sus cosas y ese nuevo proceso específico vea lo que ve Todos y lo que ven los otros?

Es con un if o tengo que usar un Switch?

```
Case 1 ve esto
Case 2 ve esto
Default Case 1 Case 2
```

No lo encontré pero puedo poner que un case vea lo que ven otros Case y que default repique lo q tenga case 1 y case 2?

Si se ve mal disculpen estoy desde un celu y no veo si se acomoda bien lo q es código.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Algo como lo que planteas, usando `switch`, seria un poco tedioso, ya que si quitamos la sentencia `break`, despues de cada `case`, podemos ejecutar las siguientes secciones hasta el `default`.

Un ejemplo de esto seria:

```
<?php

$variable = "Tp";

switch($variable){

   case "valor":
    echo "Aqui el valor\n";

   case "Tp":
    echo "He aqui Tp\n";

   case "Nada":
    echo "Un case mas\n";

   default:
    echo "Default presente\n";

}

?>
```

Lo que hemos hecho es quitar todas las sentencias `break`, lo que permite que de un `case`, se salte al otro, **ignorando si se cumple o no la condicion**.

#### Cual es el problema?

Respuesta breve: Se ignoran las condiciones previas al valor que estemos evaluando.

Lo que nos dara como resultado:

```
He aqui Tp
Un case mas
Default presente
```

Ignorando la condicion:

```
case "valor":
    echo "Aqui el valor\n";
```

#### Solucion

La solucion, mas aproximada a lo que estas buscando consisitira en hacer algo como esto:

```
<?php

$variable = "dos";

switch($variable){

   default:
    case1();
    case2();
    case3();

}


function case1(){
    echo "Case UNO\n";
}

function case2(){
    echo "Case DOS\n";
}

function case3(){
    echo "Case TRES\n";
}


?>
```

Lo que hemos hecho es resumir los procesos de los `case` en funciones y ejecutarlas todas en el `default`.

De esta manera, reusandose, obtendriamos como resultado:

```
Case UNO
Case DOS
Case TRES
```